# How do I push my data (in key:value pair) into my Firebase realtime database in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to push my data (in `key:value` pair) into my Realtime Database. This is my code:

```
DatabaseReference pay_details = database.getReference("pay/0/0/");

pay_details.push(
    {
          "Actual amount":arr.get(i).get(9),
          "Current reading":arr.get(i).get(5),
          "Employee":arr.get(i).get(1),
          "Expected amount":arr.get(i).get(9),
          "Installment":arr.get(i).get(10),
          "Meter current date":arr.get(i).get(3),
          "Meter previous date":arr.get(i).get(2),
          "Previous reading":arr.get(i).get(4),
          "Start from":arr.get(i).get(8),
          "Total charge":arr.get(i).get(7),
          "Type":arr.get(i).get(0),
          "Unit consumed":arr.get(i).get(6)
    }
);
```

This is my table structure:

[image: Click here to view]

I keep getting multiple syntax errors in the `push` section. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to send/store data in real-time database is to create an object of
Hashmap. Below is the code to achieve this objective

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
 data.put("Actual amount", Your actual amount);
data.put("Current reading", Your current reading);
data.put("Employee", Employee name);

databaseReference.child("The child name")
  .updateChildren(data)
  .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Data added successfully");

    }
  }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Failed " + e.getMessage());
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The add data to the Realtime Database you need to use [setValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#setValue(java.lang.Object)) method. In code

```
DatabaseReference pay_details = database.getReference("pay/0/0/");
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("fieldName", "fieldValue");
pay_details.setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Data added successfully.");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to add multiple children, then you can also use [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()).